# ITfoxtec Idp-initiated SSO to SP

Tags: saml-2.0

I am currently implementing a .NET Framework IdP using ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0.

I understand that the AuthController Login API endpoint in the TestIdPCore test project receives a SSO request from the SP for SP-initated SSO.

However, I don't understand how to do a IdP-initiated SSO. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .NET Framework IdP-Initiated SSO sample in the TestWebApp https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/IdPInitiatedController.cs

The sample show an SP acting as an IdP.

Comment: Please rate the answer if you think the response was helpful and can be helpful for others, thanks.